# clojuredocs integration with emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

## My Current Workflow

I need to use 'doseq'

I don't remember it's args.

I go to clojuredocs , lookup 'doseq', and look at the examples.

## My Ideal Setup

Inside emacs, I type some magic key combo, I type in doseq,
  and it EXTRACTS EXAMPLES FROM A LOCAL MIRROR OF CLOJUREDOCS
  and presents it inside my emacs browser.

## What I found via Google:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/450x84/a_clojuredocsorg_for_emacs/
```

Basically other people also want this.

## My Question:

Is there anyway to do this in emacs?

Thanks!

Comment: I always suggest keeping a browser tab always open to the Clojure Cheatsheet (and study frequently!).  http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [cider-grimoire](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/cider-grimoire.el).  In Spacemacs, I just type the leader key, followed by [h](/questions/tagged/h)[g](/questions/tagged/g).  Behind the scene, cider will perform a search on [conj.io](https://www.conj.io/) and return the result in another Emacs buffer.

Comment: You win. This is amazing. Without spacemacs, the key cinding is C-c C-d C-r. And yeah, it shows examples. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but here it is:

https://github.com/mbuczko/helm-clojuredocs

It is helm-based solution which redirects to the clojuredocs.org displaying documentation of given search phrase (if found). Most useful when used with `helm-clojuredocs-at-point` function which simply searches for phrase under the cursor.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`cider`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), `C-c C-d C-d` on a var will show you the docstring for that var. Not exactly what you're describing but for many use-cases the docstring is enough to figure out the arguments to a function.

`cider` will also show the arguments to the current function (under cursor) in the echo area.

Comment: I also use Cider. I want not aware of C-c C-d C-d. This is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: (Accepted other answer due to awesomeness of cider grimoire).